# Null Pointer Exception with checkboxes and buttons

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, nullpointerexception

Im writing a program that is a pizza ordering service, with checkboxes radioButtons so you can select different options for you pizza, then there's a readout of the price when you click the OrderPizza button. Every time I click the OrderPizza button I get a NullPointerException. The Problem it says is on the line

`pPrice = stylePrice + sizePrice + sPrice + cPrice + tPrice;`

I have no idea how to fix this and can't find out anywhere, so any help would be great. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Pizza extends JPanel
{
private double pPrice;
private JRadioButton small;
private JRadioButton medium;
private JRadioButton large;
private JRadioButton xlarge;
private JRadioButton NY;
private JRadioButton NP;
private JRadioButton CD;
private JRadioButton WW;
private JCheckBox Mozzarella;
private JCheckBox Parmesan;
private JCheckBox Goat;
private JCheckBox Feta;
private JCheckBox Tomato;
private JCheckBox Pesto;
private JCheckBox BBQ;
private JCheckBox Pepperoni;
private JCheckBox Anchovies;
private JCheckBox Olives;
private JCheckBox Basil;
private JCheckBox SDT;
private JCheckBox Sausage;
private JCheckBox Peppers;
private JCheckBox Vegetarian;
private JCheckBox Hawaiian;
private JCheckBox ML;
private JLabel PizzaNumber;
private JLabel PizzaTotal;
private int count;
private JPanel Totals;
private JButton OrderPizza;
private double sizePrice;
private double stylePrice;
private double cPrice;
private double tPrice;
private double sPrice;



public Pizza()
{
  pPrice = 0;
  count = 0;
  sizePrice=0;
  stylePrice=0;
  cPrice=0;
  tPrice=0;
  sPrice=0;
  setLayout (new GridLayout(6,1));

  JPanel size = new JPanel(); 
  JPanel basic = new JPanel();
  JPanel sauce = new JPanel();
  JPanel cheese = new JPanel();
  JPanel toppings = new JPanel();
  JPanel crustPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel Totals = new JPanel();



  //size

  TitledBorder SizeTitle;
  SizeTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Size");

  ButtonGroup PizzaSize = new ButtonGroup();

  small = new JRadioButton("Small: $10");
  medium = new JRadioButton("Medium: $13");
  large = new JRadioButton("Large: $16");
  xlarge = new JRadioButton("Extra Large: $20");


  PizzaSize.add(small);
  PizzaSize.add(medium);
  PizzaSize.add(large);
  PizzaSize.add(xlarge);


  SizeListener listener1 = new SizeListener();
  small.addActionListener (listener1);
  medium.addActionListener (listener1);
  large.addActionListener (listener1);
  xlarge.addActionListener (listener1);

  size.add(small);
  size.add(medium);
  size.add(large);
  size.add(xlarge);


  size.setBorder(SizeTitle);
  add(size);


  //style

  TitledBorder crust;
  crust = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Crust");

  crustPanel.setLayout (new GridLayout(4,1));

  ButtonGroup Style = new ButtonGroup();

  NY = new JRadioButton("New York: $0");
  NP = new JRadioButton("Neopolitan: $3");
  CD = new JRadioButton("Chicago Deep Dish: $5");
  WW = new JRadioButton("Whole Wheat: $5");

  Style.add(NY);
  Style.add(NP);
  Style.add(CD);
  Style.add(WW);


  StyleListener listener2 = new StyleListener();
  NY.addActionListener (listener2);
  NP.addActionListener (listener2);
  CD.addActionListener (listener2);
  WW.addActionListener (listener2);


  crustPanel.add(NY);
  crustPanel.add(NP);
  crustPanel.add(CD);
  crustPanel.add(WW);

  crustPanel.setBorder(crust);

  basic.add(crustPanel);




  //sauce

  TitledBorder SauceTitle;
  SauceTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Sauce");
  sauce.setBorder(SauceTitle);

  sauce.setLayout (new GridLayout(4,1));

  Tomato = new JCheckBox("Tomato: $0");
  Pesto = new JCheckBox("Pesto: $2");
  BBQ = new JCheckBox("Barbeque: $2");


  SauceListener listener3 = new SauceListener();
  Tomato.addItemListener (listener3);
  Pesto.addItemListener (listener3);
  BBQ.addItemListener (listener3);

  sauce.add(Tomato);
  sauce.add(Pesto);
  sauce.add(BBQ);

  basic.add(sauce);


  //cheese

  TitledBorder CheeseTitle;
  CheeseTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cheese");
  cheese.setBorder(CheeseTitle);

  cheese.setLayout (new GridLayout(4,1));

  Mozzarella = new JCheckBox("Mozzarella: $0");
  Parmesan = new JCheckBox("Parmesan: $.50");
  Goat = new JCheckBox("Goat Cheese: $1");
  Feta = new JCheckBox("Feta: $1");



  CheeseListener listener4 = new CheeseListener();
  Mozzarella.addItemListener (listener4);
  Parmesan.addItemListener (listener4);
  Goat.addItemListener (listener4);
  Feta.addItemListener (listener4);

  cheese.add(Mozzarella);
  cheese.add(Parmesan);
  cheese.add(Goat);
  cheese.add(Feta);

  basic.add(cheese);



  add(basic);

  //toppings

  TitledBorder ToppingTitle;
  ToppingTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Toppings: $.75 " +
      "per topping");
  toppings.setBorder(ToppingTitle);

  toppings.setLayout (new GridLayout(2,5));

  Pepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
  Anchovies = new JCheckBox("Anchovies");
  Basil = new JCheckBox("Basil");
  Olives = new JCheckBox("Olives");
  SDT = new JCheckBox("Sun Dried Tomatoes");
  Sausage = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
  Peppers = new JCheckBox("Peppers");
  Hawaiian = new JCheckBox("Hawaiian");
  Vegetarian = new JCheckBox("Vegetarian");
      ML = new JCheckBox("Meat Lover's (Pepperoni and Sausage)");

      ToppingsListener listener5 = new ToppingsListener();
      Pepperoni.addItemListener (listener5);
      Anchovies.addItemListener (listener5);
      Basil.addItemListener (listener5);
      Olives.addItemListener (listener5);
      SDT.addItemListener (listener5);
      Sausage.addItemListener (listener5);
      Peppers.addItemListener (listener5);
      Hawaiian.addItemListener (listener5);
      Vegetarian.addItemListener (listener5);
      ML.addItemListener (listener5);


      toppings.add(Pepperoni);
      toppings.add(Anchovies);
      toppings.add(Basil);
      toppings.add(Olives);
      toppings.add(SDT);
      toppings.add(Sausage);
      toppings.add(Peppers);
      toppings.add(Hawaiian);
      toppings.add(Vegetarian);
      toppings.add(ML);

      add(toppings);


  OrderPizza = new JButton("Order This Pizza");


  ButtonListener listener6 = new ButtonListener();
  OrderPizza.addActionListener (listener6);


  add(OrderPizza);


  JLabel PizzaTotal = new JLabel("Price of Pizzas: " + pPrice);
  JLabel PizzaNumber = new JLabel("Number of Pizzas " + count);

  Totals.setLayout (new GridLayout(2,1));
  Totals.add(PizzaTotal);
  Totals.add(PizzaNumber);

  add(Totals);


}


  private class SizeListener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event1)
     {
             Object source = event1.getSource();

             if (source == small)
                     sizePrice += 10;
             else if (source == medium)
                     sizePrice += 13;
             else if (source == large)
                     sizePrice +=16;
             else 
                     sizePrice += 20;
     }
   }


  private class StyleListener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event2)
     {
             Object source = event2.getSource();

             if (source == NY)
                     stylePrice += 0;
             else if (source == NP)
                     stylePrice += 3;
             else if (source == CD)
                     stylePrice += 5;
             else 
                     stylePrice += 5;
     }
   }

   private class SauceListener implements ItemListener
   {
       public void  itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event2)
       {
           if (Pesto.isSelected())
               sPrice += 2;
           if (BBQ.isSelected())
               sPrice +=2;
       }
   }

   private class CheeseListener implements ItemListener
   {
       public void  itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event3)
       {
           if (Parmesan.isSelected())
               cPrice += .5;
           if (Goat.isSelected())
               cPrice +=1;
           if (Feta.isSelected())
               cPrice +=1;
       }
   }

   private class ToppingsListener implements ItemListener
   {
       public void  itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event4)
       {
           if (Pepperoni.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Anchovies.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Basil.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Olives.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (SDT.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Sausage.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Peppers.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Hawaiian.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (Vegetarian.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;
           if (ML.isSelected())
               tPrice += .75;

       }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event5)
       {
         if (event5.getSource() == OrderPizza)
         {
           count++;
       pPrice = stylePrice + sizePrice + sPrice + cPrice + tPrice;
           PizzaNumber.setText("Number of Pizzas" + count);
           PizzaTotal.setText("Pizza Price" + pPrice);

         }

       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Debug. Print some stuff. When you know exactly what's null, trace it. No need to post here. If you still can't solve it, google "NPE java" and stuff like that.

Comment: I've always been taught: "When in doubt, cout."  The answer that Reimeus gave should solve it.  But an easy way to find out that it was the problem, would simply start with the area where the exception error is coming from.  Look at the variables that could have caused it and then print their values.  If you get an erroneous value such as -1 or some crazy address value, you know that the variable has not been properly initialized.  That should be a good start.  This method fixes about 90% of my errors.

Comment: I'd seriously recommend simpler tasks to start learning how to write computer programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the stacktrace:

You're shadowing the `PizzaTotal` and `PizzaNumber` variables in the constructor of `Pizza`. As a result the global member variables of the same name remain unassigned.
Any attempted operations on the variables will result in an `NPE` in the `ActionListener`. Replace

```
JLabel PizzaTotal = new JLabel("Price of Pizzas: " + pPrice);
JLabel PizzaNumber = new JLabel("Number of Pizzas " + count);
```

with

```
PizzaTotal = new JLabel("Price of Pizzas: " + pPrice);
PizzaNumber = new JLabel("Number of Pizzas " + count);
```

Aside: Java naming conventions indicate that variable names start with a *lowercase* letter  e.g. `pizzaTotal`. Read them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: + 1 for naming conventions. I die a little inside when I don't see them adhered too.